# Pull out all XML tags with a specific name using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation

Im fairly new to XSLT.
I have a XML that looks like

```
<ONE>
    <FOO>Foo Value 01</FOO>
         <TWO>
            <FOO>Foo Value 02</FOO>
            <BAR>Bar</BAR>
            <THREE>
                <FOO>Foo Value 03</FOO>
            <BAZ>Baz</BAZ>
        </THREE>
    </TWO>
    <FOO>Foo Value 04</FOO>
</ONE>
```

Im trying to get just the FOO tags from it:

```
<FOOS>
    <FOO>Foo Value 01</FOO>
    <FOO>Foo Value 02</FOO>
    <FOO>Foo Value 03</FOO>
    <FOO>Foo Value 04</FOO>
</FOOS>
```

They could be in any level. 
I'm having a hard time looping through my xml to get to all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `//FOO` selects all `FOO` elements and `<xsl:copy-of select="//FOO"/>` copies them through to the output so all you need is

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//FOO"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to work with XSLT and you are still struggling with XPath to select some nodes then I am sure working through any XPath tutorial or introduction will help.